# Adding current time in the subject line for Jenkins emails

Tags: jenkins

I want to add current time in the subject line of email I send using editable email notification plugin.

I know that I can use a property file and use EnvInject Plugin. But how do I make sure my property file contains the latest and greatest time, that I need?

Any other approaches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Environment Injector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to inject a custom environment variable. So instead of the file you can use a script will run automatically when you run the job and inject the time variable which you can use in your build section and extended email template section.

- Install the plugin
- Under Build environment section select "Inject environment variables to the build process"
- In "Evaluated Groovy script" section add your groovy script

Script:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
def now = new Date()
def env= [CUSTOM_TIME: now.format("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")]
return env
```

- Now you can use `${CUSTOM_TIME}` in build and extended email template section